# Change text color on scroll

Tags: css

I have the navbar change from a transparent to a white background when I scroll. The text is white on the transparent, but I want to change the text to black when scroll to get a contrast. The problem is that color:black don't work? I dont know if this is enough info to find a solution, just write a comment on what more you need.

**HTML**

```
<header class="navbar-fixed-top">
  <a href="#" id="logo" class="logo">Example<br>1001</a>
  <nav id="navigation">
      <ul class="nav__links">
        <li><a class="hvr-reveal hjem" href="#">HOME1</a></li>
        <li><a class="hvr-reveal webkamera" href="#">HOME2</a></li>
        <li><a class="hvr-reveal værmelding" href="#">HOME3</a></li>
        <li><a class="hvr-reveal status_nav" href="#">HOME4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/* navbar change on scroll */
.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled {
  background-color: red !important;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding !important on color black as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery, you can do it something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        var scroll_pos = 0;
        $(document).scroll(function() { 
            scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 210) {
                $('.hvr-reveal').css('color', '#000');
            } else {
                $('.hvr-reveal').css('color', '#fff');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I have a script already for adding a <br> when its scrolling on the logo. $(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var $nav = $(".navbar-fixed-top");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height()) {
      $('#logo').html("Example 1001");
    } else {
      $('#logo').html("Example <br> 1001");

    }

  });
}); Possible to include your script into this script? I have absolutely no experience with js.

Comment: Yes, you can add  $('.hvr-reveal').css('color', '#000');  on your scrolling script.

Comment: Is there a way to add a fadeIn transition to this code using jQuery?

Comment: @Lokesh Suman hi have question $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 300) {
        $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "white");
        $(".navbarcolortext").css("color" , "black");
      }
      else{
        $(".navbarcolortext").css("color" , "white");
        $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37)");
      }
  })
})
 i have do this background of color changed but text color no, where is problem?

Comment: @xajetin The code you posted looks fine, I suggest you double-check the class name in which you are applying the color CSS.

Comment: @xajetin You can also try `$( '.navbarcolortext' ).css( 'cssText', 'color: white !important' );` this method (In case the other CSS is overwriting your color CSS).

Answer (score 3):

You can try being more specific with your approach.
For example, try the following:

```
.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled {
  background-color: red !important;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.scrolled #navigation li .hvr-reveal {
color: black !important;
}
```

This way, even if you have conflicting Bootstrap styles, [CSS Specificity](https://dev.to/emmabostian/css-specificity-1kca) saves the day for you. Also, if the code is in an external stylesheet, try including it below the bootstrap stylesheet link in the `<head>` tag. This gives higher precedence to your external styles.

Comment: With this solution I got closer, the li items turn black. But, when I try to add the logo as well with adding #logo or .logo everything, resets to the original white

Comment: @andve Did you add #logo in the css styles? I could help you more if you could show me the problem. Try leaving a link for codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! I used a combination of what you did and js and got a result that worked.